# How to find the average closing price per year in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to find the average closing price per year in Spark?

```
sqlContext.sql(
  "select avg(closeprice), year(dt) from df0 group by year(dt)"
).show
```

The difficulty is that the column "dt" is a StringType. I cannot cast the stringType column to year/month/day. Please comment.
The following is the schema:

```
val customSchema = StructType(Array(
            StructField("dt", StringType, true),
            StructField("openprice", DoubleType, true),
            StructField("highprice", DoubleType, true),
            StructField("lowprice", DoubleType, true),
            StructField("closeprice", DoubleType, true),
            StructField("volume", IntegerType, true)
            ))

val df0 = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter",",").option("header", "true").schema(customSchema).load("./data/GSPC.csv")

df0.show()
df0.printSchema()

+----------+---------+---------+---------+----------+-------+
|        dt|openprice|highprice| lowprice|closeprice| volume|
+----------+---------+---------+---------+----------+-------+
|1950-01-03|    16.66|    16.66|    16.66|     16.66|1260000|
|1950-01-04|    16.85|    16.85|    16.85|     16.85|1890000|
|1950-01-05|    16.93|    16.93|    16.93|     16.93|2550000|
|1950-01-06|    16.98|    16.98|    16.98|     16.98|2010000|
|1950-01-09|    17.09|    17.09|    17.08|     17.08|3850000|
|1950-01-10|17.030001|17.030001|17.030001| 17.030001|2160000|
|1950-01-11|    17.09|    17.09|    17.09|     17.09|2630000|
|1950-01-12|    16.76|    16.76|    16.76|     16.76|2970000|
|1950-01-13|    16.67|    16.67|    16.67|     16.67|3330000|
|1950-01-16|    16.65|16.719999|    16.65| 16.719999|2640000|
|1950-01-17|16.860001|16.860001|16.860001| 16.860001|1790000|
|1950-01-18|    16.85|    16.85|    16.85|     16.85|1570000|
|1950-01-19|16.870001|16.870001|16.870001| 16.870001|1170000|
|1950-01-20|     16.9|     16.9|     16.9|      16.9|1440000|
|1950-01-23|16.940001|16.940001|    16.92|     16.92|1890000|
|1950-01-24|16.860001|16.860001|16.860001| 16.860001|1250000|
|1950-01-25|    16.74|    16.74|    16.74|     16.74|1700000|
|1950-01-26|    16.73|    16.73|    16.73|     16.73|1150000|
|1950-01-27|    16.82|    16.82|    16.82|     16.82|1250000|
|1950-01-30|     16.9|    17.02|     16.9|     17.02|2380000|
+----------+---------+---------+---------+----------+-------+

root
 |-- dt: string (nullable = true)
 |-- openprice: double (nullable = true)
 |-- highprice: double (nullable = true)
 |-- lowprice: double (nullable = true)
 |-- closeprice: double (nullable = true)
 |-- volume: integer (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

In latest Spark use `to_date`:

```
scala> spark.sql("SELECT YEAR(TO_DATE('3-1-1959', 'dd-MM-yyyy'))").show
+---------------------------------------+
|year(to_date('3-1-1959', 'dd-MM-yyyy'))|
+---------------------------------------+
|                                   1959|
+---------------------------------------+
```

In older versions:

```
scala> spark.sql("SELECT YEAR(CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('3-1-1959', 'dd-MM-yyyy') AS TIMESTAMP))").show
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|year(CAST(CAST(unix_timestamp(3-1-1959, dd-MM-yyyy) AS TIMESTAMP) AS DATE))|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                       1959|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I prefer a complete SQL because I was an Oracle DBA and I did a lot of SQL. Anyway, I post the answer about what I did, please feel free to comment and suggestion. Thank you.

```
// Creates a temporary view using the DataFrame
df0.createOrReplaceTempView("GSPC")

// Compute the average closing price per year for GSPC
val results = spark.sql("SELECT YEAR(TO_DATE(dt, 'yyyy-MM-dd')) AS YEAR, avg(closeprice) FROM GSPC GROUP BY YEAR ORDER BY YEAR DESC")

results.show()
```